# Get pairwise missing data rates

Tags: python, pandas

```
d = pd.DataFrame([{'a': 1, 'b': float('nan'), 'c': 5}, {'a': float('nan'), 'b': 1}, {'a': 1, 'b': 1}, {'a': 1, 'b': 0}], )

In [7]: d                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[7]: 
     a    b    c
0  1.0  NaN  5.0
1  NaN  1.0  NaN
2  1.0  1.0  NaN
3  1.0  0.0  NaN
```

I want to know,

- for rows where `a` is not null, what percentage of `b` are not null, and what percentage of `c` are not null.
- for rows where `b` is not null, what percentage of `a` are not null, and what percentage of `c` are not null.
- for rows where `c` is not null, what percentage of `a` are not null, and what percentage of `b` are not null.

The result should be a table with a,b,c index and a,b,c columns.

I've been trying lots of things but can't quite get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way use `dot`

```
s=d.notnull().astype(int)
s.T.dot(s)
Out[35]: 
   a  b  c
a  3  2  1
b  2  3  0
c  1  0  1
```

Update for percentage

```
s.T.dot(s).div(s.sum(),0)
Out[43]: 
          a         b         c
a  1.000000  0.666667  0.333333
b  0.666667  1.000000  0.000000
c  1.000000  0.000000  1.000000
```

Comment: How to get the percentages mentioned?

Comment: @Hatshepsut this percentage is for what ?

Comment: For rows where c is not null, what percentage of a are not null, and what percentage of b are not null?